# How to define a pre-processor directive in the Immediate Window?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, preprocessor-directive, immediate-window

I have some code that I want to run in Visual Studio's Immediate Window. It depends on a preprocessor directive. When I try to `#Define` it in there, I get `error CS1525: Invalid expression term ''`. My currently selected build configuration changes nothing here.

How can I run a static method, `foo.bar.MyMethod(12345)`, in the Immediate Window if I need to `#Define Test` first?

Comment: You don't have a complete C# compiler available here, just an expression parser.  Try to get ahead with View > Other Windows > C# Interactive, gives you a REPL with the Roslyn compiler.  Although the odds that a #define could work in code that was already compiled previously are not good, hard to tell from the question.

Comment: You cannot use preprocessor directives here. The immediate window doesn't seem to support defining symbols or executing code that relies on preprocessor directives.